# restoring a .SQL file in PgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, database-restore

I have backed up my database as a .SQL file. However, when I want to restore it in another database, it gives me the following error at the end of the process:

```
 pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
```

The tables are correctly restored, however, they are empty.
I have also tried to restore the file by right clicking on "public" under "Schemas". Nevertheless, the same thing occurs.
How can I restore a .SQL file in my database?

Comment: What created the `*.SQL` file and what was the command?

Comment: you could try piping it into a psql connection 
psql -d [database] -U [user] -p [port] < restoreFile.sql 
But as @AdrianKlaver says, how you produced this file will be most telling.

Comment: I right clicked on the database and chose the option "Backup".

Comment: I'm assuming you did this in pgAdmin4. When you chose the `Backup` option a dialog popped up and you had to choose options. What did you choose?

Comment: I chose "Custom" as the format. As for the dump options, all of them were set to be no except for "Blobs".

Comment: Then you got what you asked for, an empty dump file. Read this [Backup](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.28/backup_dialog.html)